# Return value containing any string within range

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, match, vlookup

I'm working on a timetabling project on Google Sheets. I am making the student timetables at the moment.

There is a teacher `overview sheet` stating which teacher is in which room for which class. I am need a formula that can return a `class code`, `room`, and `teacher` in the period slot. Each period is a column.

**The OVERVIEW sheet**

```
    MONDAY              
Teacher   Period 1  Period 2    Period 3    Period 4    Period 5
Teacher 1   07MA01 @ BG01   08MA01 @ BG01   09MA01 @ BG01   10MA01 @ BG01   11MA01 
Teacher 2   11EN01 @ B101   07EN01 @ B101   08HU01 @ B101   09EN01 @ B101   10EN01 @ B101
Teacher 3   08FR01 @ B201   10FR01 @ B201   07FR01 @ B201   11FR01 @ B201   09FR01 @ B201
Teacher 4   FREE    FREE    10GG01 @ B102   08HU01 @ B102   08HU01 @ B102
```

**The Student Timetable sheet**

| Student 1 |  | Contact: | student1@example.com |  |  |  |  | Classes (input) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| student1 | Period 1 | Period 2 | Period 3 | Period 4 | Period 5 | After School |  | 08HU01 |
| Monday |  | Teacher 1 | Teacher 2 | Teacher 4 | Teacher 4 |  |  | 08MA01 |
|  | FREE | 08MA01 | 08HU01 | 08HU01 | 08HU01 |  |  |  |
|  |  | BG01 | B101 | B102 | B102 |  |  |  |
| Tuesday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Wednesday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Thursday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| Friday |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE | FREE |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

[**The example sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hPV1Rcs40sUJWeDIOFd39p5EMLYUhxEJbj7IaUk7oQ8/edit?usp=sharing)

On the `student timetable` sheet, the administrator can enter any class code in column `I`. For example, 08HU01 and 08MA01. The formula searches for Column `I` input matches  in `overview` sheet and outputs it in the time slot ex`B3:B5`

```
  |   B
----------------
3 | teacher
4 | class code
5 | room
```

I tried vlookup but it doesn't support searching for multiple values and ranges:

```
=VLOOKUP(I2:I3[other things],OVERVIEW!B3:F6,1,1)
```

Comment: `08HU01 @ B101` 08HU01 is the class code and this B101?

Comment: 08HU01 is the classcode and B101 is the classroom.

Comment: Classes (input) order what it indicate?

Comment: This indicates the administrator to input the class codes the students are taking. for example, if a student wanted to take 08HU01, the administrator would input 08HU01 in column I.

Comment: Do you mind getting `Teacher 1 07MA01 BG01` in one cell stacked?

Comment: @Osm sure, that is ok by me :)

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add input table and expected output table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Comment: Hi, @flutters Spend some time crafting a concise explanation for the respondents to use when answering your subsequent questions; more responses is better for everyone.

Comment: This post was discussed in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248338/room-for-osm-and-themaster). cc: @Osm

Answer (score 1):

Paste this formula in `B3`, `B6`, `B9` `B13` `B15` and change the day table for day week.

```
=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TRANSPOSE(
 LAMBDA(g, IFNA(BYCOL(B$2:F$2, LAMBDA(lr, TEXTJOIN(",",1,VLOOKUP(lr, g, {2,4,3},0)))), " ,Free, "))
 (LAMBDA(fl, TRANSPOSE(SORT(TRANSPOSE(fl), SEQUENCE(COUNTA(QUERY({TRANSPOSE(fl)}, "Select Col1")), 1,1,1),0)))
 (IFERROR(TRIM(SPLIT(FLATTEN(SPLIT(
 LAMBDA(t, BYROW(I2:I, LAMBDA(q, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1 ,QUERY({t}, " Select * where Col1 = '"&q&"' ")))))
 (LAMBDA(mr, { mr,IF(SEQUENCE(ROWS(mr), 1,1,1)="",,"+")})
 (LAMBDA(y, 
 { TRIM(SPLIT(LAMBDA(x, QUERY({x}, "Select Col3 "))
 (y), "@")),QUERY({y}," Select Col2,Col1 ")})(SPLIT(FLATTEN(OVERVIEW!$B$2:$F$2&"+"&OVERVIEW!$A$3:$A$6&"+"&OVERVIEW!$B$3:$F$6),"+")))), "+")), ", ", 0)), "")))), ",")))
```

[image]

Phew, this didn't seem complicated at the beginning.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to get the timeslots for other periods working as well (assuming teachers' overview is filled?)

Comment: Yes just paste the formula and change the ranges `OVERVIEW!$B$2:$F$2&"+"&OVERVIEW!$A$3:$A$6&"+"&OVERVIEW!$B$3:$F$6` to the table you want for the rest of the week.

Comment: Hi, the next day starst at G-K, I have overwritten it with the below but it is not working.

Comment: I have changd it to this, however I cannot paste it as text due to the char limit. [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/797819761424859186/1024000188576190606/unknown.png)

Comment: Dont set it to $A:$99 just select the table, in the over weeks past the formula and change the table(Header, teacher, and data) like the example.

Comment: The headers are the same, I have only amended them to columns G-K. However, what if i were to have more teachers? Thus I had to go to $A3:$99. I am not working from the example sheet, the actual sheet has 99 teachers. Is this correct what I have done to the formula in order to change the days from column B-F to G-K?

Comment: I have accepted your edits.

Comment: See if you can open it agan follow the steps in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73843638/return-value-containing-any-string-within-range/73844931?noredirect=1#comment130414579_73844931)

Comment: I have submitted to open it again just now. :) 
BTW. is this the correct method to change the week columns? [link](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/797819761424859186/1024000188576190606/unknown.png)
I have more than 6 teachers so the change from $A:$A6 must be done to accommodate such.

Comment: @flutters Yes I checked if Teatcher is in `A` column its correct, one issue is the new formulas limitations if you dont have to have alot of teatcher dont set the rows all the way to the end, if im free i will optimize it more.

Comment: See how to change the day table [See this gif](https://i.imgur.com/Ii7rzYX.gif)

Comment: if the teachers are required to be declared every column I can do that. do not worry. however, this works fine on the example sheet attached, under the sheet named: osm's formula. just as long as the teacher reference range is the same it should not have to change per line to optimise.